# How to deal with Custom Cells when these are not visible and want to get the cell using indexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

Guys, I didn't find a clean and a simple solution for the following issue. I've a UITableViewController view which uses a UITextFieldCustomCell that I implemented.

The table has several rows, that requires the user to scroll down an enter values on each cell, which contains a UILabel and a UITextField.

Every time the user change the value on the UITextField the UIViewController gets notified and stores the value in a NSDictionary using the cell indexPath.row property, in order to identify what's the key for the cell where the value needs to be stored.

The problem is if the user keep focus on a cell and then scrolls up or down (removing the cell from the view) makes me unable to get the indexPath for the cell, since it's not visible.

So, I cannot store the value since I don't know from which cell the value is coming.

Have anyone run through this issue before?. It seems to be a common design between iPhone applications, does anyone have an idea if is this a good implementation or not?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure how the cell not being visible affects its indexPath. Could you elaborate on that more?

Comment: @raidfive It's being affected on the way I can't retrieve it from the table since it's not visible. The cellForARowAtIndexPath method only returns the cell for the visible items on the table.

Comment: @Nakardo Okay, I see what you mean now. Yes, when the cell isn't visible there is a good chance is it being released and you won't be able to access it anyways. I'd recommend taking a different approach with your app and not try to access hidden cells due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're observing `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. Are you saying it's not firing, or that it is firing, but it's no longer in any of the cells (possibly because it's in the process of being removed)?

Assuming the latter, my approach would be to use `setTag:` on the `UITextField` to make it easy to keep track of its index. This would save you from ever hunting around in your cells, even in the case that they are on the screen.

Comment: You're right, textFieldDidEndEditing: is being fired, but the indexPath for the cell that's contains the UITextField is not useful to retrieve the cell since it's not visible.

Comment: Thanks much, I just added the change you suggested and works great. :)